# android horizontal view in a listview using two base adapters

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-lists, horizontallist

I am a rookie android developer facing some issues in inflating 2 layout in a list view 
I want a horizontal row which contain image and textview as a separate layout and then call these two layout in a listview ..
I am unable to populate horizontal list

i am pasting my code for refrence 
I have used devsmart horizontal view library

```
package com.devsmart.demo;

import com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HorizontalListViewDemo extends Activity {


    private static String[] dataObjects = new String[]{ "Text #1",
        "Text #2",
        "Text #3" }; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.listviewdemo);
        Log.d("app start ", "chal gya ");

        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        Log.d("find view  ","chal gya ");
        Vadapter adapter = new Vadapter(this, R.layout.row, dataObjects);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

++++++++

```
package com.devsmart.demo;

import com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView;



import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Vadapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    String[] data;
    int resourceId;
    Vadapter(Context context , int resourceId,String[] data  ){

        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.resourceId = resourceId;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rowView ;

        if (convertView == null) {
//      
            rowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        } else {
            rowView = convertView;
        }
//      

        Log.d("start view in vertical ", "chal gya ");
        HorizontalListView hListView = (HorizontalListView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.listview);
        Hadapter horListAdapter = new Hadapter(
                context, R.layout.viewitem, data);

        hListView.setAdapter(horListAdapter);

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

+++++

```
package com.devsmart.demo;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Hadapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    String[] data;
    int resourceId;
    Hadapter(Context context ,int resourceId,String[] data){
        Log.d("start objext in horizontal ", "chal gya ");
        this.context = context;
        this.data= data;
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d("start view in horizontal ", "chal gya ");
        View retval = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(this.resourceId, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
        Button button = (Button) retval.findViewById(R.id.clickbutton);
        title.setText(data[position]);

        return retval;
    }

}
```

Comment: i don't think this can work if you use view recycling

Comment: Can you post what the view looks like now, or any error messages you are getting?

Comment: i have succesffully implemented it :) will surely share the code this weekend

Comment: what i have done .. is just define the dev-smart as a row layout with height in dp instead of wrap content